# sql error: 1222, sqlstate: s00051 lock request timeout happening in websphere only (never happens in jboss)

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, websphere

My application is throwing the below error if I use websphere and sql server

> sql error: 1222, sqlstate: s00051 lock request timeout

**NOTE:** If I use Jboss my application is working fine (the error above is not being thrown)

Below is my dev. environment for my web application:

1. WebSphere / SQL Server 2012 / XA DataSource (throwing error as mentioned above)
2. Jboss  / SQL Server 2012 / XA DataSource (working fine without error)
3. WebSphere / Oracle / XA DataSource (working fine without error)

I suspect my web application has no problem since it is working when running in another environment. The problem is only happening when I use WebSphere and SQL Server. Can anyone show me how to configure XA DataSource in WebSphere for SQL Server 2012?

Looking forward to your help!

By the way, below is the complete stacktrace for reference:

```
[2/24/17 15:35:33:404 SGT] 00000029 SystemOut     O ==> DEBUG hibernate.SQL[109]  - update TX_USER_DETAILS set GEN_NO=?, PERSON_ID=?, BIO_ID=?, ENCKEY_NAME=?, LOC_ID=?, PERSON_NAME=?, EMAIL=?, MOBILE=?, DID=?, USER_TYPE=?, ACCT_STATE=?, ACTION_BY=?, CREATE_BY=?, CREATE_DATE=?, CREATE_WSTN=?, UPDATE_BY=?, UPDATE_DATE=?, UPDATE_WSTN=?, OR_VER=?, FP_NO=?, CALLER_INFO=?, PWD=?, PWDCHKSUM=?, BIO_TYPE=?, PTHRESHOLD=? where BUSINESS_ID=?
[2/24/17 15:35:33:404 SGT] 00000029 SystemOut     O Hibernate: update TX_USER_DETAILS set GEN_NO=?, PERSON_ID=?, BIO_ID=?, ENCKEY_NAME=?, LOC_ID=?, PERSON_NAME=?, EMAIL=?, MOBILE=?, DID=?, USER_TYPE=?, ACCT_STATE=?, ACTION_BY=?, CREATE_BY=?, CREATE_DATE=?, CREATE_WSTN=?, UPDATE_BY=?, UPDATE_DATE=?, UPDATE_WSTN=?, OR_VER=?, FP_NO=?, CALLER_INFO=?, PWD=?, PWDCHKSUM=?, BIO_TYPE=?, PTHRESHOLD=? where BUSINESS_ID=?
[2/24/17 15:35:35:450 SGT] 00000029 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /home/wasapps/IBM/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/ffdc/epid_app1_7cce7cce_17.02.24_15.35.35.41335956.txt com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteBatch 749
[2/24/17 15:35:35:478 SGT] 00000029 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /home/wasapps/IBM/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/ffdc/epid_app1_7cce7cce_17.02.24_15.35.35.45035957.txt com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcStatement.executeBatch 357
[2/24/17 15:35:35:482 SGT] 00000029 SystemOut     O ==> WARN  spi.SqlExceptionHelper[144]  - SQL Error: 1222, SQLState: S00051
[2/24/17 15:35:35:483 SGT] 00000029 SystemOut     O ==> ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper[146]  - Lock request time out period exceeded.
[2/24/17 15:35:35:486 SGT] 00000029 SystemOut     O ==> ERROR internal.BatchingBatch[137]  - HHH000315: Exception executing batch [could not execute batch]
[2/24/17 15:35:35:488 SGT] 00000029 SystemOut     O ==> ERROR internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl[179]  - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [could not execute batch]
[2/24/17 15:35:35:489 SGT] 00000029 RegisteredSyn E   WTRN0074E: Exception caught from before_completion synchronization operation: org.hibernate.exception.LockTimeoutException: could not execute batch
at org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect$1.convert(SQLServer2005Dialect.java:116)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:132)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:163)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.executeBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:226)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:482)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:50)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter$TransactionAdapter$1.invoke(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:175)
at $Proxy48.beforeCompletion(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.ws.jtaextensions.SynchronizationCallbackWrapper.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackWrapper.java:66)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.RegisteredSyncs.coreDistributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:289)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RegisteredSyncs.distributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:150)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.prePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:2353)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.stage1CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:559)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:991)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:925)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:436)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:161)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.uowCommit(UOWManagerImpl.java:1237)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.uowEnd(UOWManagerImpl.java:1207)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(UOWManagerImpl.java:1143)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(UOWManagerImpl.java:630)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:290)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:279)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
at com.nec.asia.epid.web.service.impl.SubmitBiometricForCommitUpdateCallbackWithoutDupCheck$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$70b52a47.call(<generated>)
at com.nec.asia.epid.web.service.impl.SubmitBiometricRequestHandlerImpl.handle(SubmitBiometricRequestHandlerImpl.java:298)
at com.nec.asia.epid.web.service.impl.SubmitBiometricRequestHandlerImpl.handle(SubmitBiometricRequestHandlerImpl.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport$1.doInTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:285)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager$UOWActionAdapter.run(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:347)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(UOWManagerImpl.java:1116)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(UOWManagerImpl.java:630)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:290)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:279)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at $Proxy199.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.nec.asia.epid.web.api.impl.EpidWebserviceImpl.submitBiometric(EpidWebserviceImpl.java:133)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:178)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:68)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:167)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:944)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:878)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1660)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Lock request time out period exceeded.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1178)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteBatch(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1016)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcStatement.executeBatch(WSJdbcStatement.java:822)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:123)
... 99 more
```

Comment: To configure a SQL Server Datasource in WebSphere Application Server, start by seeing [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rdat_minreq.html) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rdat_minreqmssql.html)

Answer (score 1):

One difference to be aware of related to locking is that WebSphere Application Server defaults the transaction isolation level differently than most JDBC drivers do.  Specifically, for Microsoft SQL Server, WebSphere Application Server defaults you to Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ rather than Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED.  Whereas for Oracle database, both default to Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED, which might explain why you see no difference for Oracle database but do see a difference for SQL Server. You can easily configure the default to match the behavior of other application servers.

If using Liberty, configure isolationLevel on the dataSource,

```
<dataSource isolationLevel="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED" ...
```

If using traditional, you can configure [webSphereDefaultIsolationLevel](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWLGF_8.5.5/com.ibm.sr.doc/twsr_setwebspheredefaultisolationlevelproperty.html) on the data source.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you njr for your answer. It works perfectly!!! 
I've been googling for some solution for the last 2 weeks, finally I got it worked using the solution of nrj. 
Again, thanks a lot. I salute you and give you the highest score!!! 
<
One difference to be aware of related to locking is that WebSphere Application Server defaults the transaction isolation level differently than most JDBC drivers do. Specifically, for Microsoft SQL Server, WebSphere Application Server defaults you to Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ rather than Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED. Whereas for Oracle database, both default to Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED, which might explain why you see no difference for Oracle database but do see a difference for SQL Server. You can easily configure the default to match the behavior of other application servers.

If using Liberty, configure isolationLevel on the dataSource,